# python convert list of strings to CSV

Tags: python, csv, stringio

I have a list of strings like so:

```
ls = [
'Header1,Header2,Header3',
'Value1,Value2,Value3',
'Value4,Value5,Value6'
]
```

And I want to convert it to a CSV or CSV Object with the format:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|Header1|Header2|Header3|
-------------------------
|Value1 |Value2 |Value3 |
|Value4 |Value5 |Value6 |
```

Currently, I have tried:

```
import csv
import io

f = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(f)
for i in range(len(ls)):
    writer.writerow(ls[i])

reader = csv.DictReader(f)
f.getvalue()
```

But it returns something like this:

```
'H,E,A,D,E,R,1,",",H,E,A,D,E,R,2,",",H,E,A,D,E,R,3,",",V,A,L,U,E,1,","
```

etc

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your strings into iterable arrays before adding them to a row:

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
  ls[i] = ls[i].split(',')
  writer.writerow(ls[i])
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://repl.it/@esqew/DecentBarrenSearchservice)

As you found out, not doing so will iterate over the string character by character. This way, each element of the array will be iterated as a whole.